# DB changes made in a Celery task not visible in the main thread

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, celery, flask-sqlalchemy

When updating or creating a new object in a Celery task, reading the new data in the main thread fails. After the update / create I issue

```
db.session.commit()
```

From cmd it seems that the data was updated in the DB, but maybe something with the session is still getting the old data. When I update some objects in the same thread it works ok.

Comment: I'm guessing that you're using MySQL? Do you ever commit or rollback the transaction running in your main thread? If not, you've found the effects of transaction isolation.

Comment: yes using MySQL. Do you mean I need to add db.session.commit() both in Celery task code and in the main thread?

Comment: Pretty much. The default transaction isolation level in MySQL is REPEATABLE READ, which is pretty much what it sounds like. You'll have to end the transaction in order to create a new snapshot from current data, either by committing or rolling back.

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve] in the question? It'd make it a lot clearer what's happening and why (for future readers that are looking for a solution to the same issue).

Comment: Ilja Everilä I add a working example...

Answer (score 0):

actually I dont sure why we need to use commit command on Celery task to 
end the transaction and then again on the main thread. below there is working example:

this celery task is running each 7 seconds.

```
@scheduler.task()
def run_task():
    task = Tasks.get_task("task1")
    task.update_task({'status': "succeed"})
    db.session.commit()


def test_update_task(self):
    task = create_task("task1", status="active")

    log.warning("task {} status before change:{}".format(task.id, task.status))

    time.sleep(10)

    # Here the celery task will update task status from "active" to "succeed"
    db.session.commit()
    log.warning("test {} task status after Celery change:{}".format(task.id, task.status))
```